# Join 2 mp3 files with one having lower volume than other

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, overlay

I have 2 mp3 files (a.mp3 and b.mp3) and I want to overlap them using ffmpeg. How to overlap them in such a way that a.mp3's volume is low and b.mp3 volume is high so that it appears that a.mp3 is running in background of b.mp3?

Comment: How about using http://sourceforge.net/projects/audacity/ (or any other sound editing tool)? Are you trying to automate the task?

Comment: Please show the complete console output of `ffmpeg -i a.mp3 -i b.mp3`. The info will be useful for providing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the volume of audio streams using the `volume` filter.  However, you will have to re-encode the audio when you use a filter.  If you don't want to lose quality, you can always re-encode to an uncompressed format (using `-c:a pcm_s16le`, but then your file sizes will be larger.  Alternatively, you can compress the file further and leave it in the mp3 format - but naturally the quality will be reduced...

Also, you'll probably want to play around with how loud you want each stream, but here is an example that takes your `a.mp3` file and makes it 25% of it's original volume while leaving `b.mp3`'s volume alone.  In this example we are going the uncompressed audio route and going into a .wav container.

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp3 -i b.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=.25[A];[1:a][A]amerge[out]" -map [out] -c:a pcm_s16le out.wav
```

Comment: Just noting that if the inputs are stereo this will create a 4-channel output (one reason why I asked for the console output). Adding `-ac 2` will make it a stereo output if desired.